# Run a cmd command from python with a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

im trying to automate creation of tasks, i need to create a task scheduler task from cmd with a variable that im getting from the task manager, (im getting a command line of a running process and i need to create a scheduled task) what i did so far:

```
import psutil
import os
for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid','name']):
  process = proc.info 
  if process['name'] == 'powershell.exe':
     pid = process['pid']
     cmd = psutil.Process(pid=int(pid)).cmdline()
     for c in cmd:
           task = os.system('cmd/k "SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC ONSTART /TN "Tasks\task Runner" /TR {cmd}"'.format(cmd))
```

i need few things,

1. to create from every task manager process command line a task named task runner and if i have few command lines i need to call it task runner2 and so on..
2. i need to ignore massages like "the task already exist" and update the tasks

thanks!

Comment: by the way, the .format option not working i cant put a variable in the command

Comment: About the format problem, you need to update it using : .format(cmd=cmd)

Comment: Or replace `{cmd}` with just `{}`

Comment: See also `shlex.quote` to properly escape special chars `.format(cmd=quote(cmd))` at https://docs.python.org/dev/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote